# how to show a floating view on google map just like the search bar in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have implemented map successfully, but I couldn't find any help regarding this here is my implementation of google map fragment

```
SupportMapFragment fragment;
    private GoogleMap map;
    FragmentManager fm;

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.mapLarge);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapLarge, fragment).commit();

        }

    }

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if (map == null) {
            System.out.println("map is null");
            map = fragment.getMap();
  }
```

I am adding map fragment programatically (a work around to show mapview in Actionbar.Tab)
any help will be appreciated !

Comment: add an image over the map in another view...

Comment: but how to show it above the mapview fragment?

Comment: add an imageview or whatever in the layout with your fragment

Comment: i want it to display over the map, like floating over mapview that too programatically

Comment: Hi, check out this link  http://txt.do/d8qg. This should help you out.

Comment: @Dave - Can you please fix this link, it is giving 403

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, it may help someone. What I did is placed toolbar inside `CoordinatorLayout` and applied some margin to `AppBarLayout`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activity.MapActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Below is the output of above code.

[image]

Comment: how did round the `Toobar` corners?

Comment: You can make xml drawable and set the radius to make corner radius.

Comment: I did it, but then I get the `AppBarLayout` colors and shadow coming out from the corners...I made the `AppBarLayout` color as `transparent` and `elevation` as `0` to remove the shadow, but everything is disappearing, it appears to be a problem in support v24.

Comment: This code doesn't generate the image you provided....could you update the code so it will correspond with the image?