# Create a Floating ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I want to replicate this **floating** ActionBar `card` style, with **round edges** and **elevation** design found on the Android Google Maps app:

[image]

I believe I can achieve this by changing the `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` `style`, substituting the `background` with a rounded rectangle `drawable`, but I can't find the proper `theme` to edit.

Which is the proper way to achieve this effect?

---

**EDIT:**

I know there is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052852/how-to-show-a-floating-view-on-google-map-just-like-the-search-bar-in-google-map) already, but it only shows how to float the `ActionBar`, it doesn't show how to round the corners, or how to make it white, with a dark `Drawer` menu button, while the rest of the app has another theme.

Comment: You can also use a CardView. You can set elevation and rounded corners as you wish.

Comment: But if I use a `CardView` I lose all the automatic stuff the `ActionBar` already gives me, like the `Drawer` menu button, search text, etc

Comment: You can add an ImageButton with hamburger icon and open/close DrawerLayout with it. Search text is also view, EditText, you can also add to CardView, how is it related with Toolbar? Which feature does view on Google maps has more than this or the image on the link? Or you can add a background or shape to toolbar.

Comment: I tried a `shape` as the `Toolbar` `background`, but on the round corner I can still see the `Toolbar` original color spilling, as a square. Adding an image button and etc means remaking the whole `Toolbar`, and remember, the hambuer icon has animations too...I want to use what's already there, use all the methods and functionalities the `ActionBar` provides

Comment: I don't want to "hack" something that looks like an `ActionBar`, I want to change its looks.